# Preserve object identity when communicating with Web Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is there any way to preserve the identity of an object when passing it to a Web Worker?

```
// main.js
const w = new Worker('worker.js');

const data = {
  blah: 'blah'
};

// receiving from worker
w.onmessage = e => e.data === data; // <= THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE

// worker.js
onmessage = e => postMessage(e.data);
```

Comment: if you set a .equals method on data does it still exist after getting it back from the worker ?

Comment: No, it's not possible. The message communication facility clones objects, and no two distinct objects are ever `==` or `===` to each other.

Comment: @jonathanHeindl `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': function() ... could not be cloned.`

Comment: ugh thats unfortunate then you have 2 options : compare `JSON.stringify(data) `(a bit hacky ) or compare each of the subelements

Comment: Yeah, `deepEqual` could work but I was expecting more :/

Comment: @Pointy Sounds like you could make that an answer, if you wanted!

Comment: may be you can add random identifier to every message and compare basing on it?